# L10N: Trusted test data for Locale Specific Sorting

Tags: testing, sorting, localization

I'm working on an internationalized database application that supports multiple locales in a single instance. When international users sort data in the applications built on top of the database, the database theoretically sorts the data using a collation appropriate to the locale associated with the data the user is viewing.

I'm trying to find sorted lists of words that meet two criteria:

1. the sorted order follows the collation rules for the locale
2. the words listed will allow me to exercise most / all of the specific collation rules for the locale

I'm having trouble finding such trusted test data. Are such sort-testing datasets currently available, and if so, what / where are they?

"words.en.txt" is an example text file containing American English text:

```
Andrew
Brian
Chris
Zachary
```

I am planning on loading the list of words into my database in randomized order, and checking to see if sorting the list conforms to the original input.

Because I am not fluent in any language other than English, I do not know how to create sample datasets like the following sample one in French (call it "words.fr.txt"):

```
cote
côte
coté
côté
```

The French prefer diacritical marks to be ordered right to left. If you sorted that using code-point order, it likely comes out like this (which is an incorrect collation):

```
cote
coté
côte
côté
```

Thank you for the help,
Chris

Comment: be specific on what kind of data you are looking for?

Comment: attempted to clarify my question, and provided some examples in an edit.

Comment: I've found some Unicode Collation Algorithm test data at the UCA Conformance Tests page: http://www.unicode.org/Public/UCA/latest/CollationTest.html. It's a list of characters, rather than a list of words, but it suffices for testing purposes. I still haven't found anything locale-specific yet.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's what I found.

The [Unicode Common Locale Data Repository](http://cldr.unicode.org/) (CLDR) is pretty much the authority on collations for international text. I was able to find several lists of words conforming to the rules found in CLDR in the ICU Project's [ICU Demonstration - Locale Explorer](http://demo.icu-project.org/icu-bin/locexp?_=en_US&x=col) tool. It turns out that ICU (International Components for Unicode) uses CLDR rules to help solve common internationalization problems. It's a great library; check it out.

In some cases, it was useful to construct some nonsense terms by reverse-engineering the CLDR rules directly. Search engines available in the United States were not suited for finding foreign terms with the case/diacritic/other nuances I was interested in for this testing (in retrospect, I wonder if international search engines would have been better-suited for this task).